# How to create Vertical menu in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to create Vaadin vertical menu. Currently my menu is in horizontal view like this:

[image]

For that view I have code in MainLayout.java class:

```
@Theme(value = Lumo.class)
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base", enableInstallPrompt = false)
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/menu-buttons.css", themeFor = "vaadin-button")
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout implements RouterLayout {

    public MainLayout() {
        final DrawerToggle drawerToggle = new DrawerToggle();
        drawerToggle.addClassName("menu-toggle");
        addToNavbar(drawerToggle);

        final VerticalLayout top = new VerticalLayout();
        //top.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

//        top.setClassName("menu-header");


        final Label title = new Label("Converted Application");
        top.add(title);
        addToNavbar(top);

        top.add(title);
        addToNavbar(top);

        // Navigation items
        addToDrawer(createMenuLink(HomeView.class, HomeView.VIEW_NAME,
                VaadinIcon.EDIT.create()));

        addToDrawer(createMenuLink(MainView.class, MainView.VIEW_NAME,
                VaadinIcon.INFO_CIRCLE.create()));

        addToDrawer(createMenuLink(ConvertedLoginPage.class, ConvertedLoginPage.VIEW_NAME,
                VaadinIcon.LOCK.create()));

        addToDrawer(createMenuLink(Table.class, Table.VIEW_NAME,
                VaadinIcon.LOCK.create()));
    }

    private RouterLink createMenuLink(Class<? extends Component> viewClass, String caption, Icon icon) {
        final RouterLink routerLink = new RouterLink(null, viewClass);
        routerLink.add(icon);
        routerLink.add(new Span(caption));
        icon.setSize("24px");
        return routerLink;
    }
}
```

Please help me. how can I convert horizontal view of menu items into vertical view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a vertical tab bar:

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
tabs.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

Please find my full example here:

https://github.com/72services/jtaf4/blob/develop/src/main/java/ch/jtaf/ui/layout/MainLayout.java

Comment: Also, by downloading an app from https://start.vaadin.com/, you will get this and other styling in place to have a nice looking menu out of the box.

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could add your `RouterLinks` into a `VerticalLayout` and add that into the drawer.

```
 // Navigation items
VerticalLayout routerLinks = new VerticalLayout();

routerLinks.add(createMenuLink(HomeView.class, HomeView.VIEW_NAME, VaadinIcon.EDIT.create()));
routerLinks.add(createMenuLink(MainView.class, MainView.VIEW_NAME, VaadinIcon.INFO_CIRCLE.create()));
routerLinks.add(createMenuLink(ConvertedLoginPage.class, ConvertedLoginPage.VIEW_NAME, VaadinIcon.LOCK.create()));
routerLinks.add(createMenuLink(Table.class, Table.VIEW_NAME, VaadinIcon.LOCK.create()));

addToDrawer(routerLinks);
```